# Can I call a C function from a C program called by JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have already done a research about JNI,and I think I understand how it works, but I've been trying to call to a C function from another C func called by JNI.

I have 2 `.c`, HelloWorld and HelloWorld2, and a java program to call HelloWorld. HelloWorld at the same time calls to a function defined in HelloWold2 but this causes an error when executing.

> java: symbol lookup error: /home/hduser/Desktop/final2/libhello.so: undefined symbol: helloworld

Comment: Have you checked LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: I doesn't look as if the second function is the problem. It already fails when tring to call any C code from Java. Have you been able at all to call C code from Java? Please post your code.

Comment: As José already said, it's hard to help without having more details. Usually you'll see this error when you don't link anything you'll need into your `.so`. Make sure you link the object files produced from *both* your `.c` files into `libhello.so`. The linker won't complain when one is missing. You will only notice at runtime with the message you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two files:

HelloWorld.c
HelloWorld2.c

and HelloWorld is supposed to call something from HelloWorld2 you can:

- put both into the same shared lib
- put both into separate shared lib and make sure HelloWorld is linked with HelloWorld2

Make sure that shared libraries are visible by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

You can find some JNI samples here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/

Comment: How can I put them both in the same shared library? And if I put them in separate ones, how can I link HelloWorld to HelloWorld2? System.loadLibrary()?

Comment: Take a look at this sample: 

github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo018

This sample shows how to perform following calls: Java -> JNI (calling C code) -> from the JNI called code, call some other code in C.

github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo021

This sample, on the other hand, will put both C functions inside single shared lib.